# Have a Button Group in Java where all buttons can be deselected?

Tags: java, swing

I want to have a Button Group in which either only one option is selected or none of them are. At the moment, I can get it to have no options ticked by default, and then if one of them is ticked only one of them can be ticked, but I also want to be able to untick the button that was selected. Is this possible?

EDIT: Ideally without having a clear all button, as it would ruin the symmetry of my GUI. Also, here is my code thus far:

```
ButtonGroup option = new ButtonGroup();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            JCheckBox check = new JCheckBox("", false);
            option.add(check);
            row3b.add(check);
        }
```

Comment: Everything is possible, but could you please share the code of what was done?

Comment: I am guessing you are using radio buttons. Have you considered just adding an option 'none'. Eg. one button will always be selected, but their is an option to say none of the above.

Comment: Add a button to the group labelled 'none of the other options'..

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `clearSelection()` method of `ButtonGroup` :

[ButtonGroup.clearSelection()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html#clearSelection--)

> Clears the selection such that none of the buttons in the ButtonGroup
>   are selected.

Comment: How does that provide a 'one' or 'none' scenerio?

Comment: It seemed to me that it answered the "I also want to be able to untick the button that was selected" part, the other part is already working .

Comment: It sounds like they have a gui, and the user needs to be able to untick the box. So, I would guess, this provides a way for the programmer to untick it, but not the end user.

Comment: @matt : Maybe you're right, but I will leave this answer until the OP clarifies the "I also want to" part that may sound like "[as a programmer,] I also want to".

Comment: @matt, (1+) for the clearSelection(). `So, I would guess, this provides a way for the programmer to untick it, but not the end user` - you add the `clearSelection()` logic to the ActionListener of the "Clear" JButton.

Comment: I would like the user to be able to unclick one of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet demonstrates how you can clear selections using `ButtonGroup.clearSelection()`:

```
    //The buttons
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button test");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JRadioButton btn1 = new JRadioButton("Button1");
    JRadioButton btn2 = new JRadioButton("Button2");
    JButton clearbutton = new JButton("Clear");

    panel.add(btn1);
    panel.add(btn2);
    panel.add(clearbutton);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();

    //The Group, make sure only one button is selected at a time in the group
    ButtonGroup btngroup = new ButtonGroup();
    btngroup.add(btn1);
    btngroup.add(btn2);

    btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            // Do whatever you want here

        }
    });

    btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            // Do whatever you want here

        }
    });

    clearbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            // Clear all selections
            btngroup.clearSelection();

        }
    });
```

As you can see, this creates two JRadioButtons and adds them to group then makes a button that clears selections. Really simple. Or you could create your own radio button class that allows for the unchecking of the button, which is also doable relatively easily.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful, I might implement this but I'd prefer not to add a clear button as it ruins the symmetry of my GUI.

Comment: @JenniferHL3, `I might implement this but I'd prefer not to add a clear button` - then don't. Just add your code to the ActionListener. If the button is already selected, then try invokeing the clearSelection() method.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. `ButtonGroup` didn't work well, thus I had to code this behavior manually.
I had two `JCheckBoxs`, A and B, they can't be selected both at the same time; only one selected at a time or none.
I had to add `actionListener` to both `JCheckBoxs`, and had each `JCheckBox` to clear the selection the other `JCheckBox`.

Here is the code snippet :

```
JCheckBox A = new JCheckBox("A");
JCheckBox B = new JCheckBox("B");

A.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(A.isSelected()) {
            if(B.isSelected()) {
                B.setSelected(false);
            }
        }
    }
});
B.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(B.isSelected()) {
            if(A.isSelected()) {
                A.setSelected(false);
            }
        }
    }
});
```